# Restricting access to static files in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server that routes pretty much everything through middleware to check to see if you're logged in, but that only works for routes. I would also like it to work with static files in the `public` directory. How would I go about doing that?

**update**: it's better to not worry about protecting what's in the `/public` folder because express offers a `res.download(...)` feature. [Example on the Express.JS GitHub page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/downloads)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify static files are also server by express using the `express.static` middleware. In theory you can include middleware before it to handle the security. Besides the idea of the static middleware is that you only make the folder `public` statically available since its *public*.

You can find [static](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js) defined here. You can either rewrite it to allow you to inject middleware into it.

Or you can just write a naive static file router yourself.

Have you tried injecting your own security log in middleware before your static middleware.

```
app.use(security);
app.use(express.static(dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: for my scheme I'm renaming the `public` folder to `static` and making a new folder inside of that one called `public`. I would like to make the middleware to serve any files in the `static/public` folder without requiring log in so that I can use css and such for the log in form. I'm going to look up how to get the route, but if you know it off the top of your head and post it here it might save some time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Stephen `express.static(dirname + '/static/public')` would make those static. You can then implement middleware similar to `static` for `secure logged in static`