# serving downloadable file on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session-state, download

I have looked everywhere but cant find a solution for this.

I'm building a file hosting server using **node.js**. I want to use authenticated sessions/tokens to allow users access to downloadable files.

I want the downloads resumable as long as the session /token is valid. An invalid session / token will require the download to start afresh.

I dont knw what npm plugins to use or where to start.

I'm thinking of using [Simplified HTTP request client](https://github.com/mikeal/request.)

Any ideas , links anything will be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683657/restricting-access-to-static-files-in-expressjs