# ExpressJS restricting access to public files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to hide files that are being served by the Node server?  I have tried to reroute certain files and directories, but nothing is working in Express 4.X.  I have also tried to send 4XX HTTP responses when certain files are requested, but this only works for directory paths.  No matter what I do, if there is a file that is being served by Node, then the user is going to be able to see the source code.  Is this just how Express works?  Is it meant to be a development framework over a production framework?

Right now I am trying to send bad responses.

**full server.js**

```
var path = require('path'),
   express = require('express'),

var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/', express.static('dist'));

// not working
app.get('/client/config/app.js', function(req, res) {
   res.sendStatus(400);
});

app.listen(3001, function() {
   console.log('listening');
});
```

I am able to send a response if I specify a directory path, but not if I specify a full file path.  This works:

```
app.get('/client/config/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendStatus(400);
});
```

And this doesn't:

```
app.get('/client/config/app.js', function(req, res) {
   res.sendStatus(400);
});
```

I've also tried routing with `app.use`.  That didn't work either.

The best thing I can do right now to "hide" the source code is to uglify it with Gulp, but I imagine it's easy to unravel it with a JS prettifier.

Comment: Uhm, so the issue is that the user can view the source of any file served by Node? If so, that's how it works, regardless of what serverside language you are using, it's how the web in general works. Anything sent to the client, can be read by the client ?

Comment: For files that shouldn't be visible to the client at all, you just stick them in a folder that isn't part of your public folder ?

Comment: Hmmm... is there a way to restrict access?  What if I don't want the user to see my JavaScript source code?  Is that impossible to achieve?

Comment: That depends, the user shouldn't see your serverside code at all, but the javascript that is supposed to run in the browser can't be hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting access to static files in ExpressJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683657/restricting-access-to-static-files-in-expressjs)

Comment: You're right.  I think I have too much responsibility dedicated to the client.  I'll dig into server-side development I suppose.  I know to remove the `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));` statement so that everything isn't visible... thanks.

Comment: And as the answer below is stating, you'd generally have a `/public` folder containing the stuff the client is allowed to access, everything else should be hidden from the client, except the generated HTML etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## one line culprit

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

That line is saying its ok to pull anything. You could replace it with:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then put stuff in the public directory you want viewed. For routes you want to have as priority, place them before the other declarations. So you would place:

```
app.get('/client/config/app.js', function(req, res) {
 res.sendStatus(400);
});
```

above all else. However, seems like you may not need it if you just fix the first problem, then you are good. Also, see HTTP status codes. You would probably want 404 or 403 for that type of file.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Clarifying the `app.get` before the `app.use` helped.  @adenao also helped clear up some confusion I was having.  I should've stated it more clearly in my question that I know how to use EJS to restrict access to certain files.  I was just wondering if it was possible to restrict access to the source code of files that were being served (public files), but it seems that is not possible.  I think I just need to extract some work from my client to the server.

Comment: @Sudo   there is a really cool tool called git you should "check out" regarding your source files predicament. I think doing it this way isn't the best approach for exposing source files if you can avoid it.